# How to remove child (html div) from parentnode with for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, for-loop

So im trying to remove HTML div's from it's parent div.
I have a div which contains the div that need to be removed, selectedDivs.
However my current function refuses to remove more then 1 item from it's parent div...

Here's what i tried:

Console output: http://pastebin.com/KCeKv1pG

```
var selectedDivs = new Array();
canvas.innerHTML  += "<div id="+currDev+" class='DRAGGABLE' onClick='addBorder(this)>" + "<img src='/devices/" + device + ".gif'></img></div>";

 function addBorder(e) {
if (ctrlBeingpressed == true) { 
  selectedDivs.push(e);
  e.style.border = "2px dotted black";
}
```

}

```
function deleteSelected() {
            console.log(selectedDivs);
            var len = selectedDivs.length;
            for (var i = 0, len; i < len; i++){
            console.log("before html remove: " + selectedDivs.length);
            var node = selectedDivs[i];
            node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
            console.log("after html remove: " + selectedDivs.length);
                 for (var i in racks)
                 {
                 console.log(i);
                     if(node.id == racks[i].refdev)
                     {
                     console.log("Found in rack");
                        for (z = 1; z < racks[i].punkt.length; z++)
                        {
                            if(racks[i].punkt[z] != undefined)
                            {
                                if(racks[i].punkt[z].y.indexOf("S") > -1) //If it's an already defined point at an S card
                                {
                                    //Clearing the TD 
                                    $("#sTab tr:eq("+(cardsS.indexOf(racks[i].punkt[z].y)+1)+") td:eq("+(racks[i].punkt[z].x-1)+")").html("&nbsp;");
                                    $("#sTab tr:eq("+(cardsS.indexOf(racks[i].punkt[z].y)+1)+") td:eq("+(racks[i].punkt[z].x-1)+")").css("background-color","#E6E6E6");
                                }
                                else // Then it must be a P or V card
                                {
                                    $("#pvTab tr:eq("+(cardsPV.indexOf(racks[i].punkt[z].y)+1)+") td:eq("+(racks[i].punkt[z].x-1)+")").html("&nbsp;");
                                    $("#pvTab tr:eq("+(cardsPV.indexOf(racks[i].punkt[z].y)+1)+") td:eq("+(racks[i].punkt[z].x-1)+")").css("background-color","#E6E6E6");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                         console.log("Found in rack, breaking this loop");
                        delete racks[i];
                        break;
                     }
                 }
            }
```

Comment: Add more jQuery, as in `$(selectedDivs).remove()`

Comment: Is the length of `selectedDivs` 1?

Comment: Where is `racks` defined?

Comment: @kapa , rack's dont matter cause if you look in the output there isn't any output from the console.log i put there. Also, selectedDivs lenght = 2 (also look at console output!)

Comment: @adeneo i tried $(selectedDivs[i]).remove(), still no difference, it refuses to loop a 2nd time ..

Comment: how is `selectedDivs` created... can you share that code... also what is the length of `selectedDivs.length`

Comment: @Faarbhurtz my guess is it is a live NodeList and you have 2 items in the list

Comment: I see two problems: 1) You're redefining the `i` variable. There's only function and global scope in Javascript,  and I suspect you're looking for some kind of `{ }` scoping like other C-like languages. The other thing is that you've got a nested `for` loop with a break inside. I'd guess that your code is finding a rack, deleting it, and the break is breaking out of both for loops. From the code you posted, it's not clear that the `rack` loop needs to be inside the `selectedDivs` loop.

Comment: @ArunPJohny The length is 2 (look console output). It is an array of html div elements

Comment: @Faarbhurtz how are you creating it is it something like `selectedDivs  = x.chidren`

Comment: @ArunPJohny
                 var selectedDivs = new Array();
                    selectedDivs.push(e);

Comment: I'm not sure if I see the problem correctly but I think your problem is  in this part `node.parentNode.removeChild(node);` which runs just once. am I right?

Comment: @MehranHatami Yes, why would it only run once ?! this does not make sense

Comment: @jxpx777 Changing var i = 0; to i = 0 does not affect the result. Also the rack loop needs to be inside selectedDivs loop because       if(node.id == racks[i].refdev).

Comment: @jxpx777 i see what you mean now, i used the variable I for both loops, this was retarded. Make an answer with this and i will accept it !

Comment: if you give us a sample value of `racks` I can create a jsfiddle sample, and try it in real context and make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, there's a problem with resetting the value of the `i` variable within the nested loop. I took the liberty of editing the code to the way I would write it. I jQueried up some things since you're already using it anyway. (This code assumes you can target IE 9 or later and thus use `Array.prototype.forEach` and also that racks is an array, which seemed to be the case from the original.)

```
var selectedDivs = [];
$(canvas).append("<div id="+currDev+" class='DRAGGABLE' onClick='markSelected(this)'><img src='/devices/" + device + ".gif'></img></div>");

function markSelected(div) {
    if (ctrlBeingpressed == true) { 
      selectedDivs.push(div);
      $(div).css("border", "2px dotted black");
  }
}

function deleteSelected() {
    var i, z, deletedDivIDs = [];
    console.log(selectedDivs);
    selectedDivs.forEach(function(selectedDiv, index, selectedDivs) {
        console.log("Removing", selectedDiv, "at index", index);
        divIDs.push(selectedDiv.id);
        selectedDiv.parentNode.removeChild(selectedDiv);
    });
    racks.forEach(function(rack, index, racks) {
        console.log(i);
        if(deletedDivIDs.indexOf(rack.refdev) !== -1) {
            console.log("Found in rack");
            for (z = 1; z < rack.punkt.length; z++) {
                if(rack.punkt[z] !== undefined) {
                    if(rack.punkt[z].y.indexOf("S") > -1) {//If it's an already defined point at an S card
                        //Clearing the TD 
                        $("#sTab tr:eq("+(cardsS.indexOf(rack.punkt[z].y)+1)+") td:eq("+(rack.punkt[z].x-1)+")").css("background-color","#E6E6E6").empty();
                    }
                    else { // Then it must be a P or V card
                        $("#pvTab tr:eq("+(cardsPV.indexOf(rack.punkt[z].y)+1)+") td:eq("+(rack.punkt[z].x-1)+")").css("background-color","#E6E6E6").empty();
                    }
                }
            }
            racks[rack] = undefined;
        }
    });
}
```

I didn't have a chance to test this in real code since we still don't know what `racks` looks like, but hopefully this gets you further down the road.

Answer (score 1):

you have created nested for loops with the same `var i=0`, It could be your problem.

And the other point I like to point out is, if `racks` is an array you'd better not use `for(var i in racks)` because it would scan all other prototype attributes in your `Array.prototype`, which depends on what libraries you have used in your page. and If `racks` is not an array, it would scan all other properties in your `Object.prototype`, what I mean is, if it is just a iteration using `for(var i in racks)` is not safe, because adding a new Javascript library could mess with your code.

Comment: if you add the value of `racks` I can create a jsfiddle sample, and try it in real context and make it work.

Comment: Yes as i mentioned this is indeed the problem and this is solved now :) Thanks